# Is it possible to configure Save-As dialog?

Tags: 20.04, gnome

Looking for guidance on where editable configurations for Save-As dialog box would be (and which parameters can be set).

20.04.3 LTS

Gnome 3.36.8

e.g. Browser >> Print >> Save to PDF >> Save-As

The pre-populated name (I believe generally coming from html title) frequently includes problematic characters (pipes, etc). Would be nice to configure Save-As to automatically remove or replace, rather than having to manually check each time.

Comment: it would also be good for Firefox and Brave browsers (and probably others) seem to have zero  keyboard these days . all keys do nothing. except escape.